# Fractal terrain/heightmap generation

Tags: python, recursion, fractals, heightmap

I'm trying to re-implement something I did successfully a while ago, but I'm just not getting it quite right..

The fractal heightmap generation algorithm I'm using is essentially the recursive diamond-square algorithm.  It appears to run to completion fine, but the map produced just 'isnt quite right'....  It doesn't appear to successfully visit every point in the grid to determine the color, and there is residual 'structure' in the map that seems to be related to the way the grid is recursed through. I'm not certain exactly where/how the problem could be to produce what I am seeing.

The code I have so far is,

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.cm as cm
from math import sqrt
from collections import namedtuple
import random

Coord=namedtuple('Coord','x y')

class Grid(object):
    '''grid handedness, 0,0=topleft  max,max=bottomr right'''    

    def __init__(self,x,y):
        self.size_x=x
        self.size_y=y
        self.data=[ [0 for _ in xrange(x)] for _ in xrange(y) ]

    def _render_to_text(self):
        print '\n\n'
        for row in self.data:
            print [ int(n) for n in row ]

    def _render_to_colormap(self):
        plt.imshow(self.data, interpolation='nearest',cmap=cm.gist_rainbow)
        plt.show()

    def render(self):
        self._render_to_colormap()
        #self._render_to_text()

    def make(self,coordinate,value):
        self.data[coordinate.x][coordinate.y]=value

    def make_new(self,coordinate,value):
        if self.data[coordinate.x][coordinate.y]==0:
            self.make(coordinate,value)

    def get(self,coordinate):
        return self.data[coordinate.x][coordinate.y]

class FractalHeightmap(object):
    '''populates a 'grid' with a fractal heightmap'''
    def __init__(self,grid,rng_seed,roughness,
                 corner_seeds=[(0,100),(0,100),(0,100),(0,100)],
                 max_depth=3):
        self.grid=grid
        self.max_depth=max_depth
        self._set_initial_corners(corner_seeds)
        self.roughness=roughness
        self.generate_heightmap([Coord(0,0),
                                 Coord(self.grid.size_x-1,0),
                                 Coord(0,self.grid.size_y-1),
                                 Coord(self.grid.size_x-1,self.grid.size_y-1)],1
                                )

    def _set_initial_corners(self,corner_seeds):
        tl,tr,bl,br=corner_seeds
        seeds=[[tl,tr],[bl,br]]
        for x_idx,x in enumerate([0,self.grid.size_x-1]):
            for y_idx,y in enumerate([0,self.grid.size_y-1]):
                try:
                    minval,maxval=seeds[x_idx][y_idx]
                    val=minval+(random.random()*(maxval-minval))
                except ValueError:
                    val=seeds[x_idx][y_idx]
                self.grid.make_new(Coord(x,y),val)

    def generate_heightmap(self,corners,depth):
        '''corners = (Coord(),Coord(),Coord(),Coord() / tl/tr/bl/br'''
        if depth>self.max_depth: return

        #
        tl,tr,bl,br=corners
        center=Coord((tr.x-tl.x)/2,(br.y-tr.y)/2)

        #define edge center coordinates
        top_c=Coord(tl.x+((tr.x-tl.x)/2),tl.y)
        left_c=Coord(tl.x,tl.y+((bl.y-tl.y)/2))
        right_c=Coord(tr.x,tr.y+((br.y-tr.y)/2))
        bot_c=Coord(bl.x+((br.x-bl.x)/2),bl.y)

        #calc the center and edge_center heights
        avg=sum([self.grid.get(tl),
                self.grid.get(tr),
                self.grid.get(bl),
                self.grid.get(br)]
                )/4.0  ###NOTE, we can choose to use the current corners, the new edge-centers, or all
                #currenty we use the current corners
                #then do the edge centers
        offset=((random.random())-.5)*self.roughness 
        self.grid.make_new(center,avg+offset)

        #top_c
        avg=sum([self.grid.get(tl),
                self.grid.get(tr)]
                )/2.0
        offset=((random.random())-.5)*self.roughness
        self.grid.make_new(top_c,avg+offset)

        #left_c
        avg=sum([self.grid.get(tl),
                 self.grid.get(bl)]
                )/2.0
        offset=((random.random())-.5)*self.roughness
        self.grid.make_new(left_c,avg+offset)

        #right_c        
        avg=sum([self.grid.get(tr),
                 self.grid.get(br)]
                )/2.0
        offset=((random.random())-.5)*self.roughness
        self.grid.make_new(right_c,avg+offset)

        #bot_c
        avg=sum([self.grid.get(bl),
                 self.grid.get(br)]
                )/2.0
        offset=((random.random())-.5)*self.roughness
        self.grid.make_new(bot_c,avg+offset)

        self.generate_heightmap((tl,top_c,left_c,center),depth+1)
        self.generate_heightmap((top_c,tr,center,right_c),depth+1)
        self.generate_heightmap((left_c,center,bl,bot_c),depth+1)
        self.generate_heightmap((center,right_c,bot_c,br),depth+1)



if __name__ == '__main__':
    g_size=32 #//must be power of 2
    g=Grid(g_size+1,g_size+1)
    f=FractalHeightmap(g,1,10,max_depth=sqrt(g_size))
    g.render()
```

if you run it as is, you should see the colormap and see why it isnt-quite right, changing depth to differnt powers of 2 show it in different ways - values 256 and over take a while to generate

any help much appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

sorry for the out-of-topicness but I want to share another nice algorithm to generate a terrain, I started to use after I realized I didn't like diamond and square. [Here](http://www.stuffwithstuff.com/robot-frog/3d/hills/hill.html) a descrption and here an implementation:

```
#/usr/bin/python
#coding=UTF-8

import random,math

class HillGrid:

    def __init__(self,KRADIUS =(1.0/5.0),ITER=200,SIZE=40):
        self.KRADIUS = KRADIUS
        self.ITER = ITER
        self.SIZE = SIZE

        self.grid = [[0 for x in range(self.SIZE)] for y in range(self.SIZE)]

        self.MAX = self.SIZE * self.KRADIUS
        for i in range(self.ITER):
            self.step()

    def dump(self):
        for ele in self.grid:
            s = ''
            for alo in ele:
                s += '%s ' % str(alo)
            print s

    def __getitem__(self,n):
        return self.grid[n]

    def step(self):
        point = [random.randint(0,self.SIZE-1),random.randint(0,self.SIZE-1)]
        radius = random.uniform(0,self.MAX)

        x2 = point[0]
        y2 = point[1]    

        for x in range(self.SIZE):
            for y in range(self.SIZE):

                z = (radius**2) - ( math.pow(x2-x,2) + math.pow(y2-y,2) )
                if z >= 0:
                    self.grid[x][y] += int(z)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    h = HillGrid(ITER=50,SIZE = 20)
    h.dump()
```

Comment: Related to the topic at least! I shall have a look at it. 

As it goes I'm not looking  to generate realistic terrain, just a data set that has the properties of a fractally generated height-map. So either would be good, and the one you posted has less code ;)

Comment: I think it should do the job, I used this one in place of diamond and square because it's easy to tweak and with diamond and square I was getting ugly borders ^^

Answer (score 0):

I answered my own question, after much step-by-stepping thorugh the grid as it was being built up.

the calculation of the center point was incorrect,

center=Coord((tr.x-tl.x)/2,(br.y-tr.y)/2)

should have been

center=Coord(tl.x+((tr.x-tl.x)/2),tr.y+((br.y-tr.y)/2))

The first version was forgetting to add the x/y position of the sub-grid origin to the result of calculating the midpoint co-ordinates.